# Curve Fitting for equation with two parameters

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve, curves

I have two arrays:

```
E= [6656400;
    13322500;
    19980900;
    26625600;
    33292900;
    39942400;
    46648900;
    53290000]
```

and

```
J=[0.0000000021;
    0.0000000047;
    0.0000000128;
    0.0000000201;
    0.0000000659;
    0.0000000748;
    0.0000001143;
    0.0000001397]
```

I want to find the appropriate curve fitting for the above data by applying this equation:

```
J=A0.*(298).^2.*exp(-(W-((((1.6e-19)^3)/(4*pi*2.3*8.854e-12))^0.5).*E.^0.5)./((1.38e-23).*298))
```

I want to select the starting value of W from 1e-19

I have tried the curve fitting tools but it is not helping me to solve it!

Then, I selected some random values of A0=1.2e9  and W=2.243e-19, it gave me a better results. But I want to find the right values by using the code (not the curve fitting Apps)

Can you help me please?

Comment: You can use this post for inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112559/exponential-curve-fit-matlab/28113190#28113190 - Essentially, you should take the `log` of the equation so that it becomes linear in `log` space, then calculate the coefficients by linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick (and potentially easy) solution method would be to pose the curve fit as a minimization problem.

Define a correlation function that takes the fit parameters as an argument:

```
% x(1) == A0; x(2) == W
Jfunc = @(x) x(1).*(298).^2.*exp(-(x(2)-((((1.6e-19)^3)/(4*pi*2.3*8.854e-12))^0.5).*E.^0.5)./((1.38e-23).*298));
```

Then a objective function to minimize.  Since you have data `J` we'll minimize the sum-of-squares of the difference between the data and the correlation:

```
Objective = @(x) sum((Jfunc(x) - J).^2);
```

And then attempt to minimize the objective using [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html):

```
x0  = [1.2E9;2.243E-19];
sol = fminsearch(Objective,x0);
```

I used the guesses you gave.  For nonlinear solutions, a good first guess is often important for convergence.

If you have the Optimization Toolbox, you can also try [`lsqcurvefit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) or [`lsqnonlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) (`fminsearch` is vanilla MATLAB).

Comment: Thanks!

Your Genius :)